# How do I select a specific id from a JSON file in swift?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, decodable

I'm trying to just select one of the entries in my JSON file and am struggling to do so. Here is the list part of my code so far:

```
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                List {
                    ForEach(regions) { regions in
                   NavigationLink(destination: RegionsListView(regions: regions)) {
                       RegionButtonView(regions: regions)
                   }
              }
        }
            }
        }
        }
```

And here is the `if statement`:

```
    let regions: Region
    
    var body: some View {
        if regions.id != nil {
            SCaliView()
        } else if regions.id != nil {
            BAView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Region: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String

}
```

I want to make it so that when a certain `id` is selected, it will go to a certain view.

Comment: What is regions? How is it initialized?

Comment: You're running an if statement on two separate Bools, its possible that both could be true or false, and based on your statement that you only want to show one, I'm sure this isn't the correct implementation. Try making the different views part of the same Bool

Comment: But how would I make it so that it would select a specific `id`? because I have 7 id's total that will be going to 7 different views. What line of code would I use? @SergioBost

Comment: @yvngbucky I just posted something that should help you out, but you have to centralize all of your ids so you can use them in a single switch statement like in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can literally throw whatever kind of view you'd like after the case using a ViewBuilder. Text Views, Nested Stacks although its a little clear passing pre-constructed views. Just replace the Int with whatever you id type is, although Int should work and then modify the case statements to handle your different ids

```
 @ViewBuilder func jsonSelector(using id: Int) -> some View {
      switch id {
         case 0:
      ViewA()
         case 1: 
      ViewB()
         case 2: 
      ViewC()
         case 3: 
      ViewD()


     }

}
```

Then just throw it in your view

`jsonSelector(using: myID)`

If you add some code, I'll edit the answer to fit your use case but this is a general fix

Comment: Glad it helped. Hit the check button please. Trying to level up :)